# Flag message showing as "removed during a deletion" in the flag history

Tags: bug, flags, flag-history

I recently flagged a [(now deleted) NAA on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54906146/how-to-install-fasttext-library-in-python/63261696#63261696) (10k+ on SO) ([mirror for everyone](https://sentinel.erwaysoftware.com/posts/226887)).

The flag is shown as "removed during a deletion" in the flag history:

> [image: Flag handling message showing as "removed during a deletion" in the flag history page]

What does this mean? Is the flag "helpful", "declined", "disputed" or something else?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1512/discussion-on-question-by-daniil-flag-message-showing-as-removed-during-a-delet).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This has been reverted for the time being. To [quote Yaakov](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/400046):

> ### This fix has been temporarily reverted - we need to better define the flag types to which this applies. Will update here when we have further changes

Comment: What is going to happen with flags currently marked as "removed during a deletion"? Left alone or updated to helpful or ... ?

Comment: I don't know that we can do anything about them for the moment. I'll make a note of the concern and see if we can address the flags impacted by this once we have a solution.